# Codeigniter insert_id() strange issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having some issues with Codigniter 3 last insert_id.

I want to get the last inserted org_id. But in error i put the below command to get the last inserted id after a query to log the transaction.

```
            // grab org_id from insert
            $insert_org_id = $this->db->insert_id();    

            // create preset levels
            $this->preset_levels($insert_org_id);
```

So it correctly returned the last inserted id from the log table. Controller extract below:

```
            // send org_data to model for db input
            $this->org_model->add_org($org_data);                                   

            // audit log 
            // serialize data array for audit log
                $serialised_array = serialize($org_data);       

                // specify audit log title
                $log_title = 'Create Organisation';     

                // send data to audit log model 
                $this->audit_model->add_log($serialised_array,$log_title);      
            // end audit log entry  

            **// grab org_id from insert
            $insert_org_id = $this->db->insert_id();    
            // create preset levels
            $this->preset_levels($insert_org_id);**
```

So, i thought fine, ill just move this:

```
            // grab org_id from insert
            $insert_org_id = $this->db->insert_id();    

            // create preset levels
            $this->preset_levels($insert_org_id);
```

after the command to add the org, see controller extract below:

```
            // send org_data to model for db input
            $this->org_model->add_org($org_data);   

            **// grab org_id from insert
            $insert_org_id = $this->db->insert_id();    
            // create preset levels
            $this->preset_levels($insert_org_id);**                                                 

            // audit log 
            // serialize data array for audit log
                $serialised_array = serialize($org_data);       

                // specify audit log title
                $log_title = 'Create Organisation';     

                // send data to audit log model 
                $this->audit_model->add_log($serialised_array,$log_title);      
            // end audit log entry
```

But it doesnt return any value? The inserted org_id is non numeric, could that be the problem?

Both inserts are very simple database inserts, see below:

Add organisation method in org_model

```
// add new organisation
public function add_org($org_data) {
    $this->db->insert('organisations', $org_data);  
}
```

And, add log method in audit_model

```
// add audit log entry
public function add_log($serialised_array,$log_title) {     

    // capture current date & time for audit log
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    // build array of log data
    $log_data = array(
        'log_datetime'  => $date,
        'log_org_id'    => $this->session->userdata('org_id'),
        'log_user_id'   => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
        'log_user_name' => $this->session->userdata('username'),
        'log_title'     => $log_title,
        'log_detail'    => $serialised_array
    );
    // insert log data to db
    $this->db->insert('audit_log', $log_data);  

}
```

So why does one work and the other not? Whats different?

Answer (score 2):

`insert_id()` should return the last auto increment value generated for a given connection. If org_id is not a numeric field, it cannot be auto increment, therefore the `insert_id()` will not return any value for it.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Is there a simple command to get the last value of a non numeric non auto increment insert?

Comment: There is no such command (ofc you can always do a select), since if a column is not auto increment, no value is assigned automatically to the column, apart from its default value. You have to generate the non-numeric id in your php or sql code and explicitly insert it into the table.